# Dropbox API requests performance issues

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

The issue we dealing with is when moving or copying files in Dropbox server to another folder in Dropbox server.
The API requires to send request for each file separately. That takes way too long. 
Maybe You provide some kind of batch request so I could move more than one files per request?
I also know the ability to move all folder content, but it doesn't work on our case, cause we need only subset of files to move.
If we try to flush many request at once threw several connections, we get 'Server Unavailable' or 'File Locked' errors and need to repeat request again.

Tl;DR;
To move 1000 files that already are in Dropbox server it takes over 30 minutes.

What possible solutions You have to increase the performance?

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201667939-API-requests-performance-issues-.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this. A possible solution would be to copy the folder and delete the files you don't need.

Comment: DropBox API allows to move folder only with less than 10'000 files in it.

Comment: We talked with DropBox support, and there is not way to improve performance. We are planning to move to another file storage provider with batch requests support.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API now provides a batch endpoint for moving files. You can find the documentation here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-move_batch